# Facebook "Like" button encoding

Tags: encoding, joomla, facebook-like

I've put like button on joomla site with cyrillic text:
http://womanew.kz/index.php/2011-10-22-01-42-12/2011-11-01-05-34-04/147-2011-11-07-06-22-02

When I push like button facebook's scraper incorrectly encodes the page.

Also I've created static test html page equal to this URL (http://womanew.kz/test.html), and it scrapes well.

All two pages have equal content, but the problem page is generated from Joomla PHP script.

Also I've noticed that scraper reencodes not full document (it keeps head block unchanged), please see its "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" debuging page on facebook.

What can I do to struggle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**When I did this I use this manual and didn't have such problem. This is for Joomla website:**

1.Go to the Facebook developer page here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box

2.Enter the page number (found in your Facebook page URL) of your Facebook page.

3.If you don't have one, go to Facebook Create Page wizard and create a Brand >> Website page for your site.

4.Enter the height (typically 400 pixels) that you want for the Like widget

5.Click the Get Code button to generate the Facebook Code.

6.Open the Joomla Administrator on your site

7.Navigate to the Module Manager

8.Click the New button

9.Select Custom HTML

10.Paste the code into the HTML box (make sure the editor is turned off).

11.Give the module a name

12.Click the Hide Title radio button

13.Select the Module Position where you want the widget to appear

14.Click Save

Also, take a look at http://www.abolkog.com/portal/tutorials-how-to/100-how-to-add-a-facebook-like-box-to-your-joomla-site

*Hope, it will help you!*

Comment: Thank you Mark.

I've found a bug in this site. One of joomla's modules was truncating UTF-8 strings in byte boundaries and this was created one-byte bug character in the page, after this character scrapper starts using incorrect encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a bug in the site. One of joomla's modules was truncating UTF-8 strings in byte boundaries and this was created one-byte bug character in the page, after this character scraper starts using incorrect encoding.